# hybris. how to pool two workflow templates in one

Tags: java, workflow, workflow-foundation, sap-commerce-cloud

I try two develop hybris workflow template.

I have template1, template2, template3.

I want to create following template:

```
template1->template2->template3->template2->template3
```

Is it really in hybris ?

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: point - use workflowtemplate as part another workflowTemplate

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is. Please check the back office administration menu in hmc > System > Workflow administration.